# Tunneling Linux to a Windows VPN

Tags: linux, windows, vpn, juniper

At my work we have a VPN (Juniper) that only runs on Windows.

But as a Java Dev I prefer to use Linux or my OS X Macbook.

The issues is that the VPN client of my company it's only available for Windows. I already tried different software in Linux like OpenConnect without success. I was wondering if there's any way to make a VM that runs windows, exceute the VPN client there a make a tunnel to access that VPN or a Proxy on the Windows host machine.

Thanks!

Comment: It is very likely that the VPN client doesn't support split tunneling. That is a security feature that most companies have. You are going to need to work this out with you company.

Comment: i've never used the following and no idea, you probably know better than me, bu maybe WINE may help. i've heard of it running windows things within linux. Also maybe you could find out a bit about exactly what VPN server they use, and then be able to find out what it takes for a VPN client to be compatible.